# Split a long page-wide table into 2 pages in a 2-page ACM document

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I am using the `acm-sigconf` template that is a 2-column document. And I have a long table that is also wide, so I need:

- The table should occupy 2 columns
- The table should split into the next page.
- The text inside each cell should wrap.

Currently, I am using `table*` but the table will spill into the footer area. If I change that to `longtable*`, it will just jump to almost outside of the page. Below is the MWE. Could you help?

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table*}[tbp]
    \caption{Game features that potentially affect a game's ranking.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.2\linewidth} 
                    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.36\linewidth} 
                    >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{0.03\linewidth} 
                    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth}}
    \toprule
        \textbf{Column 1}                                          
        & \textbf{Column 2}                                                                        
        & \textbf{Column 3} 
        & \textbf{Column 4}                                                                    
        \\
    \midrule
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.               
        & Lorem ipsum                                                                            
        & 1       
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
        \\
    \midrule
        Total
        & 
        & 99999
        \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:my-table}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A longtable is not a float. Try nesting your longtable in a `strip` environment from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle). And perhaps consider using the `xltabular` package to have the exact text width (it brings the functionalities of longtable to `tabularx`).

Comment: @Bernard  I tried put `longtable*` inside `\begin{strip}.. \end{strip}`. It still does not reposition in the page.

Comment: Did you try `xltabular` ?

Comment: @Bernard could you post a working solution? I have tried it but it does not break into next page

Comment: Unfortunately, the  `strip` environment seems to be incompatible with `acmart`. It works fine with the basic `article`  class, and I obtain two error messages with `acmart`.

Comment: @Bernard could you try with `xltabular`. I have not figured out the exact syntax despite reading the document